# Ember: The response to store.query is expected to be an array but it was a single record Error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I keep getting the error:

> Error: Assertion Failed: The response to store.query is expected to be an array but it was a single record. Please wrap your response in an array or use `store.queryRecord` to query for a single record.

This is my back end:

```
router.route('/')
.post(parseUrlencoded, parseJSON, function (request, response) {
    var advancedStanding = new models.AdvancedStandings(request.body.advancedStanding);
    advancedStanding.save(function (error) {
        if (error) response.send(error);
        response.json({advancedStanding: advancedStanding});
    });
})
.get(parseUrlencoded, parseJSON, function (request, response) {
    //var l = parseInt(request.query.limit);
    //var o = parseInt(request.query.offset);
    var AdvancedStanding = request.query.filter;
    if (!AdvancedStanding) {
        models.AdvancedStandings.find(function (error, advancedStandings) {
            if (error) response.send(error);
            response.json({advancedStanding: advancedStandings});
        });
        //models.AdvancedStandings.paginate({}, { offset: o, limit: l },
        //    function (error, students) {
        //        if (error) response.send(error);
        //        response.json({advancedStanding: advancedStandings.docs});
        //    });
    } else {
        //        if (Student == "residency")
        models.AdvancedStandings.find({"studentInfo": AdvancedStanding.studentInfo}, function (error, advancedStandings) {
            if (error) response.send(error);
            console.log(advancedStandings);
            response.json({advancedStudent: advancedStandings});

        });
    }
});
```

The is my front end:

```
showStudentData: function (index) {
this.set('currentStudent', this.get('studentsRecords').objectAt(index));
this.set('studentPhoto', this.get('currentStudent').get('photo'));
var date = this.get('currentStudent').get('DOB');
var datestring = date.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
this.set('selectedDate', datestring);

var self2 = this;
this.get('store').query('advanced-standing',{filter:{studentInfo:'585df32e0bf2ba5ea6951592'}})
.then(function(records123){
  console.log(records123);
});
```

}

Does any have any idea on what this is happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `query` function expects multiple results. so you need to use `queryRecord`

```
this.get('store').queryRecord('advanced-standing',{filter:{studentInfo:'585df32e0bf2ba5ea6951592'}})
.then(function(records123){
  console.log(records123);
});
```

or wrap your response in an array literal

```
if (!AdvancedStanding) {
    models.AdvancedStandings.find(function (error, advancedStandings) {
        if (error) response.send(error);
        response.json([{advancedStanding: advancedStandings}]);
        // you were returning a single object
        // note the array is now wrapping your previous result

    });
    //models.AdvancedStandings.paginate({}, { offset: o, limit: l },
    //    function (error, students) {
    //        if (error) response.send(error);
    //        response.json([{advancedStanding: advancedStandings.docs}]);
              // you were returning a single object
              // note the array is now wrapping your previous result
    //    });
} else {
    //        if (Student == "residency")
    models.AdvancedStandings.find({"studentInfo": AdvancedStanding.studentInfo}, function (error, advancedStandings) {
        if (error) response.send(error);
        console.log(advancedStandings);
        response.json([{advancedStudent: advancedStandings}]);
        // you were returning a single object
        // note the array is now wrapping your previous result
    });
}
```

Comment: I changed it from query to queryRecord, however, the console.log(records123) returns null.

Comment: are you sure a student is being found?

Comment: @Jackie  you have router.route('/') in your post but your code is going to 'advanced-standing' on the front end, so are your routes correct?

Comment: Yeah a student is being found. The server logs show a list of advanced standings. Below is 1 of the many advanced standings that have been returned from my console.log(advancedStandings); in my backend

{ _id: 5896457ed246a62f45315f6b,
    course: 'sdfsf',
    description: 'sdfsdf',
    units: 'sdfsdf',
    grade: null,
    from: 'sfdfs',
    studentInfo: 585df32e0bf2ba5ea6951592,
    __v: 0 }

the data doesn't make any sense because I am just testing for now.

Comment: look at your network tab. what is the actual response?

Comment: I'm not sure what to look at in the network tab, I have never used it before.

Comment: open your dev tools, (in firefox or chrome `f12`); then find the ajax request, click it and then click the response tab

Comment: I am receiving the correct response but I don't know how to read the data from the response.

Comment: change `console.log(records123);` to `console.log('found', records123);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134880/discussion-between-therealmrcrowley-and-jackie).